# Retrieve data from colections with tdocument references

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

For a pymongo flask application I need to build a query to retrieve data from two collections MongoDB containing reference documents, please if anyone has a clue, I have struggled for hours. The idea is that for a certain day (for example day 1), I want to be able to receive employees from the respective shift

```
db.days:

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e83ec781c9d440000ed36a8"
    },

    "shift_date": {
        "$numberInt": 1
    },

    "emploee_name": [{
        "$oid": "5e7d4baa1c9d4400004f4d95"
    }, {
        "$oid": "5e7d4bc11c9d4400004f4d96"
    }, {
        "$oid": "5e7d4bc11c9d4400004f4d97"
    }]
}

db.emploees:

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e7d4baa1c9d4400004f4d95"
    },

    "emploee_name": "Kevin"
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e7d4baa1c9d4400004f4d96"
    },

    "emploee_name": "Queen"
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e7d4baa1c9d4400004f4d97"
    },

    "emploee_name": "Mark"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything with just [`find_one()`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one) and [`get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

```
day = db.days.find_one({'shift_date': 1})

for emploee_id in day.get('emploee_name'):
    emploee = db.emploees.find_one({'_id': emploee_id.get('_id')})
    if emploee is not None:
        print(emploee.get('emploee_name'))
```